# How to use getIntent() in a class that does not extend Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a String from a class "Play" which extends Activity by using:

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
Intent i = new Intent(Play.this, Receive.class);
String category;

data.putString("key", category);
i.putExtras(data);
```

Then, the "Receive" class which is a non Activity class and does not extend Activity will receive the String from "Play".

But when I try to receive the data using this code:

```
Bundle receive = new Bundle();
String passed;

receive = getIntent().getExtras();
passed = receive.getString("key");
```

I get an error on the word "getIntent()" and suggests me to create a method getIntent().

What is the possible solution to this problem?
THANKS!

Comment: Intents are intended for communication between Activities. There is no way to send information via an Intent to a simple class. You should use other ways of communication to send information to a "Non-Activity" class

Comment: you can check my posted answer if this is the only case you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intent is not nessesary here. You can just do something like this:

Play.class :

```
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
```

and in Receiver.class :

```
Play playObject = new Play();
passed = playObject.getCategory();
```

Or you can use static field as pKs mentioned but it's not always a good pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `public static variable` and use it to store data and fetch data from other class.

> As intents don't work without extending Activity class in Android.

In your case , it would be like.

`public static category="some category";`

To access in another class ,

`String dataFromActivity=NameOFClassWhereCategoryIsDefined.category;`

Comment: I am sorry. I'm just new to Android and java stuff. I am just learning while I am doing it. Thanks, your suggestion worked fine.!

Comment: @ejmtv It is an ok approach only if you have small data that has to be shared across the application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot getIntent(); from within a class that does not extend Activity. As Sprigg mentioned you would have to use other means of communication between the classes.