# Sharing between Activities, first class extends Activity but Other don't

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent, android-activity

I have this code which takes input from user, I basically want to get the name and phone number from user for a small Contacts app. When user enters the data in the EditText fields, I extract the data and do this--

```
        String _name,_phone;
        _name=name.getText().toString();
        _phone=phone.getText().toString();
        Intent in = new Intent(this, DatabaseHandler.class);
        in.putExtra("name", _name);
        in.putExtra("phone", _phone);
        startActivity(in);
```

but the other class isn't inherited from the Activity class but actually from "SQLiteOpenHelper"

> > public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper

So the method  `getIntent().getExtras().get("name");`  won't work, may be because the class isn't inherited from the Activity  or something else. So, how can I share the data from the first activity to the second activity called "DatabaseHandler"

Comment: intent is used for the navigation between activities not between java classess

Comment: Your question was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937410/how-to-use-getintent-in-a-class-that-does-not-extend-activity/14937577#14937577

Comment: Could you mark an ans. as correct if your issue was solved so that it isnt unanswered ? tnks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use two technique: 1.take help of an `Application` class. or 2.take help of `SharedPreference`.

i am going to tell about 2nd approach. because it is easy to use.

in your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class before calling `DatabaseHandler` write this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("username", your_username);
editor.putInt("password", your_password);
editor.commit();
```

now call `DatabaseHandler`, also pass `_context`.

now in your `DatabaseHandler` class write this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String username = prefs.getString("username");
String password = prefs.getInt("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using intent why don't you use shared preferences for put whatever values you want in it, so that you can get anywhere in your app need not that should be an activity compulsory just pass context to that class in order to use shared preferences.

Comment: and if you want only getIntent() then it is possible only in case of activity not JAVA class.For that you have to retrieve that values in activity and pass that values to respective JAVA class.

Comment: you can pass context to that class from activity and there you can use   this.getSharedPreference().

Comment: This is my DatabaseHelper class not an Activity and I have used shared preference by passing context to it from calling activity...'SharedPreferences Pref;
                Pref = myContext.getSharedPreferences("SessionManagement", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Pref.edit();    
                editor.putString("UserId", mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("UserId")));'

Comment: unable to undo downvote...Please Edit your answer so that I can remove downvote and give you upvote..

Comment: actually what you want I am not getting I have called my DatabaseHelper class from Login activity and passed application context there. In DatabaseHelper I have written constructor for that and using that context now I can put or get values from sharedPreferences.

Comment: I am not asking about your answer...Edit your answer once that's what I have said..unable to remove downvote because the vote is locked if you edit than I can remove it..

Comment: @Pragnani please check I have edited my answer help me by removing your down vote thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just use getters and an instance of the producer to get the value ? Something like

Producer.java

```
public String getName() {
    return username;
}

public String getPwd() {
    return password;
}
```

and use these in the consumer class as something like :

Consumer.java

```
Producer producer = new Producer();
producer.getName();
producer.getPwd();
```

You could also refer to [How to use getIntent() in a class that does not extend Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937410/how-to-use-getintent-in-a-class-that-does-not-extend-activity/14937577#14937577)